# Woocommerce - Make Admin Order General Field Read Only

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'd like to make select fields in the Admin Order General page read only (namely 'Created Date').  I've used the following code to list out all the fields:

```
function echo_admin_order_data( $order ){
$order_data = $order->get_data();
foreach($order_data as $item) {
        echo $item;

    }
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'echo_admin_order_data' );
```

What function can I use to hook into specific fields such as :

```
14T22:00:40+00:002018-03- <<-- Order created date
```

Rather the field name is

```
date_created is at 2018-03-14T22:00:40+00:00
```

and Set editable = 'false'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make date created from Backend order edit page "readonly", try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'make_order_date_read_only', 100, 1 );
function make_order_date_read_only( $order ){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $('form#post input[name=order_date]').attr('readonly','readonly').removeClass('date-picker').css({'width':'106px','line-height':'20px'});
            $('form#post input[name=order_date_hour]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            $('form#post input[name=order_date_minute]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]